# Facing calculator app error in android

Tags: android

Friends I searched a lot but didnt get answer of my question. I am trying to make an android calculator. A simple one , actually its just a single module of my bigger app...

In this firstly I need users to enter 1st and 2nd sunber and select if he would like to add, sub, mul, divide or get mod..Then there is a textview in which result would be displayed.

This is the code I am using :

Java code:

```
package com.droidacid.apticalc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class numSys extends Activity{


EditText etnumber1;
EditText etnumber2;

Button badd;
Button bsub;
Button bmul;
Button bdiv;
Button bmod;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.numsys);

    etnumber1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number1);
    etnumber2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number2);



    String number1 = etnumber1.getText().toString();
    String number2 = etnumber2.getText().toString();

    final Double number1D = Double.parseDouble(number1);
    final Double number2D = Double.parseDouble(number2);

badd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    double resultD = number1D + number2D;
    String result = "result :"+resultD;
    TextView tvresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvresult);
    tvresult.setText(result);
    }
});

bsub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    double resultD = number1D - number2D;
    String result = "result :"+resultD;
    TextView tvresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvresult);
    tvresult.setText(result);
    }
});

bmul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

double resultD = number1D * number2D;
String result = "result :"+resultD;
TextView tvresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvresult);
tvresult.setText(result);
}
});

bdiv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

double resultD = number1D / number2D;
String result = "result :"+resultD;
TextView tvresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvresult);
tvresult.setText(result);
}
});

bmod.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

double resultD = number1D % number2D;
String result = "result :"+resultD;
TextView tvresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvresult);
tvresult.setText(result);
}
});



}

 }
```

This is the logcat error :

```
05-04 10:24:18.098: E/AndroidRuntime(1321): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.droidacid.apticalc/com.droidacid.apticalc.numSys}: java.lang.NumberFormatException:
```

Please dont rate this post as negative. I am just trying to learn and trying to solve this issue since last more than 24 hours. Tried everything posted on Stack Overflow.

Thanks

Comment: Check that the String can be parsed as double (spaces, characters cannot be parsed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be your problem:

```
    String number1 = etnumber1.getText().toString();
    String number2 = etnumber2.getText().toString();

    final Double number1D = Double.parseDouble(number1);
    final Double number2D = Double.parseDouble(number2);
```

You're trying to parse an, at this point, empty EditText into a Double value. Either that, or you have some default text in the EditText that you're trying to parse.

This (probably) causes the NumberFormatException.

Answer (score 0):

```
final Double number1D = Double.parseDouble(number1);
final Double number2D = Double.parseDouble(number2);
```

the exception means  that `number1` or `number2` can not be converted to `double`. Try to `trim` the number1 and number2 string